# Distancia entre coordenadas

Tags: python, python-3.x, geojson

Estoy intentando calcular la distancia entre coordenadas, los datos a comparar provienen de una consulta sql y un geojson.

Los datos de la consulta son puntos que corresponden a propiedades mientras que los datos del json son vias.

Necesito tomar el primer punto y calcular la distancia hacia la via mas cercana, asi sucesivamente con todos los puntos de la consulta en un radio de 20 KM, si no encuentra nada en ese radio que la salida sea 'No hay vias cercanas'.

Logre llegar hasta leer los datos de la consulta y estoy detenido al leer el json y calcular las distancias en ese radio.

```
import geopandas as geo
import pyodbc

cnn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=****;Database=****;uid=****;pwd=****')

sqlcmd = ("Select lng, lat from inmuebles \
           inner join InmuebleDivisionPolitica b on a.idInmueble = b.idInmueble \
           inner join DivisionPolitica c on c.idDivisionPolitica = b.idDivisionPolitica \
           inner join Direccion d on d.idDivisionPolitica = c.idDivisionPolitica where d.geom is not null")

cursorConsulta = cnn.cursor()
cursorConsulta.execute(sqlcmd)

sh = geo.read_file('C:\Ferrocariles\ViasServicioPasajerosActivos.shp')

with open('C:\Ferrocariles\ViasServicioPasajerosActivos.geojson', 'w') as f:
    f.write(sh.to_json())

for r in cursorConsulta:

    latOrigen = str(r[1])
    lngOrigen = str(r[0])
```

los datos del geojson a modo de ejemplo son los siguientes

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "id": "0",
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "Name": "Lï¿½nea G - Buenos Aires - Tapiales",
                "LINEA": "BELGRANO",
                "RAMAL": "G",
                "KM": 16.62,
                "ACTIVA": "SI",
                "CABECERAS": "Buenos Aires - González Catán",
                "SERVICIO": "Trenes urbanos en el AMBA",
                "CONCESION": " (Estatal, Nación)",
                "OBSERVAC": ""
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        -58.39323087479187,
                        -34.64522852285068
                    ],
                    [
                        -58.39493519860744,
                        -34.64593911202303
                    ],
                    [
                        -58.39540370387294,
                        -34.64612018963881
                    ],
                    [
                        -58.39577715270643,
                        -34.64624297063709
                    ],
                    [
                        -58.3961720086682,
                        -34.64636735300267
                    ],
                    [
                        -58.39657393244798,
                        -34.64649079664271
                    ],
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "Name": "Lï¿½nea G: Tapiales - Gonzalez Catan",
                "LINEA": "BELGRANO",
                "RAMAL": "G",
                "KM": 18.47,
                "ACTIVA": "SI",
                "CABECERAS": "Buenos Aires - González Catán",
                "SERVICIO": "Trenes urbanos en el AMBA",
                "CONCESION": " (Estatal, Nación)",
                "OBSERVAC": ""
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        -58.51164133538381,
                        -34.70237187907585
                    ],
                    [
                        -58.50886122230304,
                        -34.70446888060354
                    ],
                    [
                        -58.50807265291671,
                        -34.70505643669129
                    ],
                    [
                        -58.5075876903448,
                        -34.70536763434288
                    ],
                    [
                        -58.50672881971201,
                        -34.70591466418704
                    ],
                    [
                        -58.50612050168868,
                        -34.70630557185193
                    ],
                    [
                        -58.50586890953366,
                        -34.70652771805103
                    ],
                    [
                        -58.50574833497523,
                        -34.70665678170097
                    ],
                    [
                        -58.50557625423573,
                        -34.70683067509435
                    ],
                    [
                        -58.50545796343254,
                        -34.70698015127397
                    ],

                ]
            }
        }
```

Comment: Que es lo que quieres medir? la distancia entre un punto y una recta o entre un punto y otro punto? es decir quieres saber la distancia de un punto a la vía del tren o a una estación en particular?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho en realidad las vias como se muestra en el json son todos puntos que forman una linea.
Necesito tomar la primera lat/lng que devuelve la consulta y en una radio de 20 km determinar la distancia al punto/linea de la via y asi sucesivamente.
Y si la distancia en entre el punto y la via

Comment: Me queda clarísimo que una línea se describe por una sucesión de puntos  y que tu json es justamente eso, lo que me confundió es `Estoy intentando calcular la distancia entre coordenadas..` quería confirmar y lo has hecho que el calculo que pides es la distancia de un punto a una recta.

Comment: Usa haversine [Es un módulo disponible en la web](https://pypi.org/project/haversine/)